# C#: Cannot Parse String to double

Tags: c#, parsing

_day.Latitude = "64.128339"

_day.Longitude = "-20.995595"

```
public override void Prepare(ItineraryDay day)
{
    _day = day;

    var isParseLatitude = double.TryParse(_day.Latitude, out var latitude);
    var isParseLongitude = double.TryParse(_day.Longitude, out var longitude);

    _dayPositionInfo = new DayPositionInfo(
        latitude,
        longitude,
        _day.RouteName);
}
```

[image]

As you can see in the picture, Latitude and Longitude are valid double values, but Parse does not work and returns false?
Why, I do not understand something?

Comment: `double.TryParse` is culture-dependent, which seems like a bad default to me but there you go.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your current culture doesn't use the `.` character as a decimal separator, that's why `Double.TryParse` returns `false`.

If you know that the decimal separator is always a `.`, you can do something like this:

```
bool isValidLatitude = Double.TryParse("64.128", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double latitude);
```

PS: if you need to check what is the decimal separator of your current culture, use

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Convert.ToDouble("64.128339");
double.Parse("64.128339");
```

Comment: What does this mean…?

Comment: conversion types to double data type in C#

Comment: This will fail in exactly the same way for the OP, for exactly the same reason, even while It Works On Your Machine™